# interface<T> binding in Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a common datacontainer 
interface IDataContainer

I use it for different types of T
IPerson, ISuperMan etc

In castle i regsiter it with

```
container.AddComponentWithLifestyle<IDataContainer<IPerson>, DataContainer<Person>>(LifestyleType.Transient);
container.AddComponentWithLifestyle<IDataContainer<ISuperMan>, DataContainer<SuperMan>>(LifestyleType.Transient);
```

at runtime castle creates the dependency with eg.

```
IDataContainer<IPerson> test = container.GetService<IDataContainer<IPerson>>();
```

but it fails with an unable to cast...the classes implements the interface and namespaces are correct etc.

The call

```
IPerson test = container.GetService<IPerson>();
```

Works (with the registration of `<IPerson,Person>`)

Cant castle resolve an `interface<T>` or ?

Comment: Rephrase your question. I can't understand a word.

Answer (score 2):

So this is way late, but I think I know what you're trying to do here. I'm able to get this to pass:

```
IDataContainer<IPerson> test = container.GetService<IDataContainer<IPerson>>();
```

By registering components like this:

```
public class IoC
{
    public static void SetUp()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddComponent<IPerson, Person>();
        //container.AddComponentWithLifestyle<IDataContainer<IPerson>, DataContainer<Person>>(LifestyleType.Transient);
        //container.AddComponentWithLifestyle<IDataContainer<ISuperMan>, DataContainer<SuperMan>>(LifestyleType.Transient);
        container.AddComponentWithLifestyle("DataContainers", typeof(IDataContainer<>), typeof(DataContainer<>), LifestyleType.Transient);
    }

    public void TestOne()
    {
        SetUp();
        var test = container.GetService<IDataContainer<IPerson>>();
        Assert.That(test, Is.Not.Null);
    }

    public void TestTwo()
    {
        SetUp();
        var test = container.GetService<IPerson>();
        Assert.That(test, Is.Not.Null);
    }
}

internal interface IDataContainer<T> { }
internal class DataContainer<T> : IDataContainer<T> { }

internal interface IPerson { }
class Person : IPerson { }

internal interface ISuperMan { }
class SuperMan : ISuperMan { }
```

The two lines that are commented out are the two lines that exist in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Windsor. You get a casting error because C# 2.0 and 3.0 do not support generics covariance. You're probably making `DataContainer<T>` implement `IDataContainer<T>`, which means that `DataContainer<Person>` implements `IDataContainer<Person>` and not `IDataContainer<IPerson>` which is what you're requesting from the container.